# How to calculate the average monthly consumption sales in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

How to **calculate** the average monthly consumption sales in sql **server 2008**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT year(OrderDate) as [year],left(datename(month,OrderDate),3)as [month],Qty as QTY FROM DailyDispatch where CustID=1 ) as s PIVOT ( SUM(QTY)FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr,may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))as P
```

i am getting the result,but i want to do the sum of all months and dividing it to the current month.
for eg the all sum of sales up-to this September is 1000,so i want to 1000/9 and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention much about your data, but you could do the following from what I understood:

```
-- Declare Table Varibale
DECLARE @DailyDispatch TABLE (OrderDate DATETIME, Qty INT, CustID INT)

-- Insert some test records
INSERT INTO @DailyDispatch VALUES (GETDATE()+ 90, 12000, 1),(GETDATE()+60, 11000, 1), (GETDATE()+30, 10000, 1), (GETDATE(), 9000, 1)
                                    ,(GETDATE()-30, 8000, 1), (GETDATE()-60, 7000, 1), (GETDATE()-90, 6000, 1),(GETDATE()-120, 5000, 1)
                                    ,(GETDATE()-150, 4000, 1), (GETDATE()-180, 3000, 1), (GETDATE()-210, 2000, 1),(GETDATE()-240, 1000, 1)

-- Finally, the SQL:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT year(OrderDate) AS [year]
        ,left(datename(month, OrderDate), 3) AS [month]
        ,Qty / DATEPART(m, OrderDate) AS QTY
    FROM @DailyDispatch
    WHERE CustID = 1
    ) AS s
PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR [month] IN (
            jan
            ,feb
            ,mar
            ,apr
            ,may
            ,jun
            ,jul
            ,aug
            ,sep
            ,oct
            ,nov
            ,dec
            )) AS P
```

It would help others to answer your question if you had include some test data (with the help of table variables, for example) in your question, so others wouldn't have to spend time on the dataset to help you out. Hope this helps.